# Instagram login with swift 5, getting ["error_type": OAuthException, "error_message": Invalid platform app, "code": 400]

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, instagram-api

I'm trying to login with instagram with new documentation and getting error like **Invalid platform app, "code": 400**

I am successfully getting **code** using **https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize** and after getting code i am calling **https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token** for getting access_token but it gave me error.

I am following this documentation : **https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started**

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Instagram App ID, Instagram App Secret and remove #_ from received code. Then Make your post request below format.

```
let urlString = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"

let appendedURI = "client_id=\(API.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID)&client_secret=\(API.INSTAGRAM_CLIENTSERCRET)&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=\(API.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI)&code=\(code)"

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "Post"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type");
    request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.httpBody = appendedURI.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("result=",dataString!)


let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("result=",dataString!)
                do {

                if let accDetail = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any] {

                    let accessToken = accDetail["access_token"] as! String

                    let userID = accDetail["user_id"] as! Int64

                    completion("success", accessToken, userID)

                }

            }catch let error {



            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Why? Instagram, whhhyyyy?!?! You have to send data "x-www-form-urlencoded" but receive the response as JSON... consistency?! Anyway big thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks, this code work and resolve 200 ok issue